# Pointer one-past-variable

Tags: c, for-loop, pointer-arithmetic

From what I know it is perfectly legal in C to check if pointer is one element past the end of an array like this:

```
char arr[16];

for (char* ptr = arr; ptr != arr + (sizeof arr / sizeof arr[0]); ++ptr) {
   // some code
}
```

My question is if it is well defined and legal to do something like this (note that this code is just an example to show my point. In real code I have functions handling arrays and I wonder if I can pass just pointer to local char variable and size 1):

```
char c;
for (char* ptr = &c; ptr != (&c + 1); ++ptr) {
   // some code
}
```

Comment: As for the first snippet, in a case of `char arr[]` this works, because `sizeof(char) == 1`. Semantically, however, you're adding a _number of elements_ in the array, not its size, so, in general, you better use `arr + (sizeof arr / sizeof arr[0])`.

Comment: `arr + arr + (sizeof arr / sizeof arr[0])` is nonsense. You probably meant `arr + (sizeof arr / sizeof arr[0])`.

Comment: @Lundin Indeed, fixed it already

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From the C Standard (6.5.6 Additive operators)

> 7 For the purposes of these operators, a pointer to an object that is
> not an element of an array behaves the same as a pointer to the first
> element of an array of length one with the type of the object as its
> element type.

So this loop

```
for (char* ptr = &c; ptr != (&c + 1); ++ptr) {
   // some code
}
```

is correct.

Answer (score 0):

The main reason for the rule is that it allows "iterator-like" access (think C++ `iterator` if that's familiar). This is valid and well-defined:

```
char arr[16];
const char* begin = arr;
const char* end   = &arr[16];

for(char* ptr=begin; ptr!=end; ptr++)
```

However, we are not allowed to de-reference `arr[16]`, just point at it.